# Best way to add "Related Documents" to a SharePoint list in 2010

Tags: 2010, list, document-library

I'd like to have a SharePoint list with a field called "Related Documents" where I could easily do a lookup from another document library and multi-select any relevant documents.

When viewing the list, the "Related Documents" would be clickable to see their contents but it would not actually be storing the documents in the list as it would be a link to the document in the document library.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you might want a document set with a Link to a Document content type enabled. This would allow you to create a main document in the document set, then add addition related files stored somewhere else using the Link to a Document content type. This creates a simple link to the file.